# Sorting Custom Object Array in swift with different parameter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of a custom class

```
class GameInfo {
var gameStatus :String
var country : String
var isSelected : Bool
}
```

Here, `gameStatus` may be "*"/"1-0"/"1/2-1/2"

I want to sort the array first by `isSelected`, then `gameStatus`, then `country`.

I tried `sortInPlace` but didn't work for me.

suppose this is my array

```
let list = [
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2-1/2", country: "France", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1-0", country: "Italy", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Germany", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "0-1", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
 GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2-1/2", country: "France", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "UK", isSelected: false)
]
```

Selected games should be on top if with in selected game there is any live game that game should be on top even with in any game related to my country that game on top

suppose my country is Italy then sorted order of array is

```
     GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "0-1", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2-1/2", country: "France", isSelected: true),
     GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Germany", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "UK", isSelected: false)
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1-0", country: "Italy", isSelected: false),
   GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2-1/2", country: "France", isSelected: false),
```

Comment: We posted several answers to your question. Please provide a feedback and if an answer does solve your problem please accept it.

Comment: as I want it does not solve my problem. I have to manage this via using many array and arrayfiltermethod :)

Answer (score 1):

try this (old style Objective-C array sorting):

```
let sortedArray = (yourArray as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([
  NSSortDescriptor(key: "isSelected", ascending: true),
  NSSortDescriptor(key: "gameStatus", ascending: true),
  NSSortDescriptor(key: "country", ascending: true)
]) as! [GameInfo]
```

In that case, your GameInfo class must be like this. It's not the easy way to resolve your problem, just for info. Sorting with multiple conditions is very easy and natural with NSSortDescriptors but for Objective-C only, unless our swift classes are under some conditions (implementations).

```
class GameInfo : NSObject {
    var gameStatus: String?
    var country: String?
    var isSelected: Bool

    init(gameStatus: String, country: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.gameStatus = gameStatus
        self.country = country
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }

    override func valueForKey(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if (key == "gameStatus") {
            return self.gameStatus
        } else if (key == "country") {
            return self.country
        } else if (key == "isSelected") {
            return self.isSelected
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not work. `warning: object 0x7fed10e19f50 of class '__lldb_expr_118.GameInfo' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[__lldb_expr_118.GameInfo valueForKeyPath:]`

Comment: I've missed somethings. In order to use NSSortDescriptor, we the GameInfo class must inherit NSObject class then override valueForKey. I update my answer for this solution. Otherwise, you can implement your own rule in .sort function for swift (see appzYourLife's answer)

Comment: Implement the GameInfo class as above, it must work.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can write your own logic into the closure you pass to `sort`.

So given this class

```
class GameInfo {
    var gameStatus: String
    var country: String
    var isSelected: Bool

    init(gameStatus: String, country: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.gameStatus = gameStatus
        self.country = country
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

and this list

```
let list = [
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "A", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "A", country: "France", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "B", country: "UK", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "B", country: "Germany", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "A", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "B", country: "UK", isSelected: false)
]
```

you can created a sorted list this way

```
let sorted = list.sort {
    guard $0.isSelected == $1.isSelected else { return $0.isSelected }
    guard $0.gameStatus == $1.gameStatus else { return $0.gameStatus < $1.gameStatus }
    guard $0.country == $1.country else { return $0.country < $1.country }
    return true
}
```

### Solution 2

You can make your `GameInfo` class conform to `Comparable`.

```
class GameInfo: Comparable {
    var gameStatus: String
    var country: String
    var isSelected: Bool

    init(gameStatus: String, country: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.gameStatus = gameStatus
        self.country = country
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

func ==(left: GameInfo, right: GameInfo) -> Bool {
    return
        left.isSelected == right.isSelected &&
        left.gameStatus == right.gameStatus &&
        left.country == right.country
}

func <(left: GameInfo, right: GameInfo) -> Bool {
    guard left.isSelected == right.isSelected else { return left.isSelected }
    guard left.gameStatus == right.gameStatus else { return left.gameStatus < right.gameStatus }
    guard left.country == right.country else { return left.country < right.country }
    return true
}
```

Now you can just invoke `sort` without the need of furthers params.

```
let sorted = list.sort()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

your class look like below

```
import UIKit

class GameInfo : NSObject {

    var gameStatus :String = ""
    var country : String = ""
    var isSelected : Bool = false

    init(gameStatus: String, country: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.gameStatus = gameStatus
        self.country = country
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

And use this code for sorting. As per your need, you can set **ascending** parameter.

```
let list :NSArray = [
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2/21", country: "France", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1-0", country: "UK", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "*", country: "Germany", isSelected: false),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "0-1", country: "Italy", isSelected: true),
    GameInfo(gameStatus: "1/2-1/2", country: "UK", isSelected: false)
]

let isSelectedDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isSelected", ascending: false)
let gameStatusDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "gameStatus", ascending: true)
let countryDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "country", ascending: true)


let sortedResults: NSArray = list.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([isSelectedDescriptor,gameStatusDescriptor,countryDescriptor])

dump(sortedResults)
```

Comment: @downvoter : please also give reason so I can keep in mind in future and if there is no reason feel free to downvote..